# Why webpack can convert es6 to es5 without babel?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I very new to Webpack and babel.
I know that webpack is a module bundler and it enables use of babel-loader to loads ES2015+ code and transpiles to ES5.
But when i config like this in webpack.config.js without using babel

```
import path from "path";
import webpackNodeExternals from "webpack-node-externals";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default {
    entry: {
        server: "./app.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    target: 'node',
    node: {
        __dirname: false,
        __filename: false,
    },
    watch: true,
    externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsdom": "^20.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.0",
    "puppeteer": "^19.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

I still es5 code in bundle.js file. I'm so confused right now ....

Comment: Show the bundle.js code, and clarify what code you are confused.